# How can I use netrw in SpaceVim?

Tags: neovim, netrw, spacevim

I tried `nvim ftp://[address]//path/to/code.txt` but that not work for SpaceVim, it opened an empty file while it was not empty on my remote machine.

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `autoload/SpaceVim/layers/core.vim`.

Search for the line:
`let g:loaded_netrwPlugin = 1`
and comment it out.

This works and *mostly* doesn't break stuff for me, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

`netrw` disabled by default in `core` layer. Add to file `~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml`:

```
[[layers]]
name = 'core'
enable_netrw = true
```